# how exactly does http.sys work

Tags: http, iis, tcp, windows-kernel, http.sys

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of how IIS works.

http.sys i understand is one its major components. However, i have been having trouble finding easily digestible information about it. I couldn't get a good mental model going until i heard about the WSK, then i think it all fell into place.

From a lot of random googling a little experimentation this is my current high level understanding of why it exists and how it does it's stuff.

Why:

Port sharing, and higher performance caching.

How:

User mode processes use the WinSock api to open a socket listening on a port to gain access to the networking subsystem, e.g. tcp/ip. Kernal mode software like the http.sys driver uses Winsock Kernal Sockets (WSK) api to achieve the same end using the same pool of TCP port numbers as the WinSock api.

IIS, a web service or anything that wants to use http registers itself with http.sys using a unique url/port combination. http.sys opens up a socket on this port using WSK (if it hasn't already for another url/port combination with the same port) and listens.

When the transport layer (tcpip.sys) has reconstructed a load of ip packets back into an http request that a client sent it gives it to http.sys via the port in the request. Http.sys uses the url/port number to send it the the appropriate process which parses it however it pleases.

I know it seems like I'm answering my own question but I'm really not that sure of myself on this and would like some closure so i can get on with more interesting things.

Am i close?

Comment: i guess i am right then?

Comment: Here is architecture description to give understanding how it works togerther http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture. And here is some information on HTTP.SYS caching http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817445/en-us and how you can tune it in windows registry.
About port sharing check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager

Comment: I wish this was not closed and there was more info.....